# Angular switch from ng-show to ng-repeat filter / how to

Tags: angularjs

What is the correct syntax to switch from my simple `ng-show` to  a filter in my `ng-repeat`? (`item in list | filter:{item.value == 'abc'}` or so)

```
<ol ng-repeat="item in list">
    <li ng-show="item.value == 'abc'">test</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use ng-repeat inside `<ol>` tag.

This will repeat `<ol>` tag each time with single `<li>`.

Use ng-repeat in `<li>` tag to repeat `<li>` tag inside `<ol>` tag and use filter with ng-repeat.

use like this :

```
<ol>
  <li ng-repeat="item in list | filter: { value : 'abc' }">test</li>
</ol>
```

[working plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/coyDlIdE1O74TeZrrfcn?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ol ng-repeat="item in list | filter:{value: 'abc'}">
    <li>test</li>
</ol>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/uw0LNygWbj4Njhp1n7PN?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ol ng-repeat="item in list | filter: {value: 'abc'}">
    <li>test</li>
</ol>
```

[Angular Filter doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Answer (score 0):

You can use nf-repeat Filter

```
<ol ng-repeat="item in list | filter : {value : 'abc'}">
<li>test</li>
</ol>
```

[read AngularJS API Document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)